XSLT replacing Json with plain text equivelent
Hey all I am newish at XSLT and have a XSLT output that contains some json within elements.
I've been looking around to see if there is anyway for XSLT to replace the json with just a string:
Ex:
<company:Cause 
   xmlns:company="http://example.com/company" 
   xmlns:j="http://example.com/j" 
   xmlns:s="http://example.com/s" 
   xmlns:nc="http://example.com/nc"
>
   <j:Cause s:id="Cause-08D628B86EF2">
      <nc:DescriptionText>{"code":"PC","description":"Probable Cause"}</nc:DescriptionText>
      <nc:ActivityDate>
         <nc:DateTime>2018-10-02T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:ActivityDate>
      <j:Name>{"code":"PC","description":"Probable Cause"}</j:Name>
      <company:Augmentation>
         <j:Stat>
            <j:DescriptionText>{"code":"PC","description":"Probable Cause"}</j:DescriptionText>
         </j:Stat>
      </company:Augmentation>
   </j:Cause>
</company:Cause>

Is there anything I can add to the XSLT in order to do this on the fly? Anything already built into XSLT?

Can you share the XSLT that you have tried so far? Does this answer help you?

Any chance that you can use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 conformant processor?

Also, your XML is missing namespace declarations...

I think the most you can do in XSLT 1.0 is use the translate() function to remove the JSON special characters {}[]":,. But this could also remove them when they are  part of a value. And you may have other escaped characters that this won't handle properly.

I added namespace declarations to your XML so that it's well-formed. In future, please remember to check (e.g. with an XML-aware text editor)  that the sample XML you post is actually well-formed, so that people can use it for testing. It's easy to cut your real data down to a manageable sample and accidentally break it, especially by missing namespace declarations.

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, and you wanted to process JSON properly, tt would certainly be possible to build a full JSON parser using recursive named templates, but that may be overkill. Much simpler to do as y.arazim suggests and just strip out the "special" JSON characters by translating them all into   spaces, and then use the normalize-space() function to convert each run of multiple spaces into a single space. e.g.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
   xmlns:company="http://example.com/company" 
   xmlns:j="http://example.com/j" 
   xmlns:s="http://example.com/s" 
   xmlns:nc="http://example.com/nc"
>

  <!-- identity template copies anything that doesn't need munging -->
  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- these elements are munged to remove special JSON characters -->
  <xsl:template match="j:Name | j:DescriptionText | nc:DescriptionText">
    <xsl:variable name="unwanted-characters">{":,}</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="
        normalize-space(
          translate(., $unwanted-characters, '       ')
        )
      "/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

NB the string of spaces which appears as the third parameter to the translate() function should be the same length (or longer!) than the second parameter (containing the unwanted characters). The translate() function takes the first parameter and for each character in that string it looks for that character in the second parameter, and if it's found, it replaces it with the character at the same position in the third parameter. So the third parameter being entirely spaces means that every one of those unwanted characters will be replaced with a space.
Result:
<company:Cause xmlns:company="http://example.com/company" xmlns:j="http://example.com/j" xmlns:nc="http://example.com/nc" xmlns:s="http://example.com/s">
   <j:Cause s:id="Cause-08D628B86EF2">
      <nc:DescriptionText>code PC description Probable Cause</nc:DescriptionText>
      <nc:ActivityDate>
         <nc:DateTime>2018-10-02T00:00:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:ActivityDate>
      <j:Name>code PC description Probable Cause</j:Name>
      <company:Augmentation>
         <j:Stat>
            <j:DescriptionText>code PC description Probable Cause</j:DescriptionText>
         </j:Stat>
      </company:Augmentation>
   </j:Cause>
</company:Cause>

NB you will need to use the proper namespace URIs rather than the dummy values I added here.

Awesome Conal! Thanks for helping me out with this!

XSLT 3 can parse/process JSON:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:function name="mf:try-json-to-xml" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="json" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:try>
      <xsl:sequence select="if (json-to-xml($json)) then true() else false()"/>
      <xsl:catch select="false()"/>
    </xsl:try>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="text"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="text" match="fn:*[@key and not(*)]">{@key} {.}{if (position() lt last()) then ' ' else ()}</xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and mf:try-json-to-xml(.)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)" mode="text"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Example fiddle running SaxonJS with pure JavaScript in the browser.
Example fiddle running Saxon HE 12 Java with CheerpJ 3 in the browser.
XSLT 3 has been the current version of XSLT since 2017 and is currently supported on a variety of platforms through free to use libraries like e.g. Saxon HE 12 Java for Java, SaxonC 12 for C/C++ and Python and PHP, SaxonJS 2.6 for JavaScript and Node.js and Saxon HE 10 .NET for the .NET framework or .NET 6/8.
There are also commercial offerings like Altova RaptorXML or SaxonCS.

Hey Martin thanks for the visuals on fiddle! Very helpful as well but I have to do it in 1.0 sadly.
